# Is it possible to duplicate all values in a table while updating one or more columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with many columns, and what I would like to do is duplicate all of the rows in the table, but also update one of the columns to a new value.

For example lets say I have the table below. I want to add to my table a duplicate of each row, except instead of BASIC access, it will have 'ADVANCED':

**Before:**

```
NAME, GENDER, ACCESS
----------------------
STEVE, MALE, BASIC
MOLLY, FEMALE, BASIC
```

**After**

```
NAME, GENDER, ACCESS
----------------------
STEVE, MALE, BASIC
MOLLY, FEMALE, BASIC
STEVE, MALE, ADVANCED
MOLLY, FEMALE, ADVANCED
```

Is there a way to do this without specifying all columns?  I have 60 columns in the table, and the structure can change (meaning columns may be added, removed, renamed, etc).

Is it possible in Oracle SQL to automate this?

Comment: Don't confuse Oracle SQL with PL/SQL; PL/SQL is something else altogether and has nothing to do with your question. I will edit your post in this regard.

Comment: OK, so suppose you do "this" today. ("This" meaning duplicating existing rows while changing the ACCESS.) Tomorrow you add 1000 rows to the table. If you apply the process again, mindlessly, then you will end up with duplicates of the old rows where `ACCESS = 'ADVANCED'`. Is that what you want? Are you sure you thought through the future side effects of doing this more than once?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t (name, gender, access)
    select name, gender, 'ADVANCED'
    from t;
```

You need to list all the columns.  You can shorten the manual process by using a query to generate the list.  If you had to do this a lot and always knew you were leaving out `access` and `access` is the last column, you could use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select . . . -- all but access
    from t;

insert into t ( . . . )
    select v.*, 'ADVANCED'
    from v_t;
```

Or you could use dynamic SQL to generate the statement.

However, I don't recommend any of those.  Instead I would be concerned about a data model where you are regularly adding and modifying the columns in a table.  That sounds dangerous.

Comment: As described, I want to to this without specifying all columns since the table has nearly 60 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying all the columns? With some help of a "temporary" table, here's how:

Your current table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (name varchar2(10),
  3     gender varchar2(20),
  4     caccess varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'steve', 'male', 'basic' from dual union all
  3    select 'molly', 'female', 'basic' from dual;

2 rows created.
```

- Create a "temporary" table as a copy of the "original" table
- update column you want to modify
- copy the whole "temporary" table to the "original"
- drop the "temporary" table

---

```
SQL> create table test_temp as select * From test;

Table created.

SQL> update test_temp set caccess = 'advanced';

2 rows updated.

SQL> insert into test select * From test_temp;

2 rows created.

SQL> drop table test_Temp;

Table dropped.

SQL> select * From test;

NAME       GENDER               CACCESS
---------- -------------------- --------------------
steve      male                 basic
molly      female               basic
steve      male                 advanced
molly      female               advanced

SQL>
```

Apparently, that works, but - what if the original table is *huge*? It takes a lot of space, and its copy takes approximately twice as much. Why are you doing that, anyway?

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing that but as you said It seems like a lot of extra writes to the database.

I was really hoping Oracle has something similar to SELECT * REPLACE that google SQL supports. Sounds like it does not though.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: I checked the link you posted; yes, it looks like a nice option. Though, as far as I know, Oracle doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below method with anonymous block to avoid listing columns in insert statements

```
CREATE TABLE ACCESS_CHN
(NAAME VARCHAR2(100),
GENDER VARCHAR2(20),
ACCCESS VARCHAR2(30))

INSERT into ACCESS_CHN values('STEVE','MALE','BASIC');

INSERT into ACCESS_CHN values('MOLLY','FEMALE','BASIC');

COMMIT;

DECLARE

column_list varchar2(2000):=NULL;
plsql_block VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

select LISTAGG(column_name,',') within group (order by column_id)
into column_list
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='ACCESS_CHN';

plsql_block :=  'CREATE TABLE ACCESS_CHN_BKP  as select '|| column_list || ' from ACCESS_CHN';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block;

plsql_block := 'UPDATE ACCESS_CHN_BKP  set ACCCESS=''ADVANCED'' ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block;

COMMIT;

plsql_block :=  'CREATE TABLE ACCESS_CHN_FINAL  as select * from ACCESS_CHN
union all
select * from ACCESS_CHN_BKP';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block;

END;

--To rerun drop tables ACCESS_CHN_BKP and ACCESS_CHN_FINAL
```